# How to get remote host IP information

Tags: command-line, remote

What command should i write to get this output?

```
Connection to 45.79.83.164 closed by remote host.
```

I need to know any command that will give me the IP for remote host connection.

Note that I am using Ubuntu Server 20.04.4.

Comment: To clarify, you you want to get the IP of whatever machine you're SSH-ed into?

Comment: Please elaborate on what you were doing when the error occurred.

Comment: Hello. what version of Ubuntu are you using?

Comment: @David in this case the ubuntu version does not matter

Comment: @france1 The version of Ubuntu should be included in each and every question. How do you know 100 percent it has no affect? You do not. Maybe he is using 22.04 which is off topic right now or an EOL version or a non Ubuntu version.

Comment: @David there are actually questions (this one included) where the Ubuntu version truly doesn't matter at all. This relates to generic SSH functionality, which is the same across *all on-topic Ubuntu versions*. So in this case (as well as many other), the particular version is of no actual concern.

Comment: @Artur Meinild Read what I said off topic like 22.04 and EOL

Answer (score 1):

When you connect with SSH to a machine, you usually connect either to an IP address or to a hostname.

The message you see with `Connection to X.X.X.X closed by remote host.` appears when you loose SSH connection to the server.

To find the IP address of a machine where you know the hostname, you can use nslookup:

```
nslookup <hostname>
```

Or if domain search is not configured:

```
nslookup <hostname>.<domain>
```

If you're already logged into a machine, you can get the internal IP address with this command:

```
hostname -I
```

And the full hostname and domain with this command:

```
hostname -A
```

I believe these are your best options.